# Firebase Functions Service Accounts with Two Projects

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have two firebase projects, one for production and one for development. I've created service account keys for both projects and I initialize admin in my functions folder like so:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("./service-account.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  storageBucket: "some-app.appspot.com",
});
const db = admin.firestore();

module.exports = {
  db,
  admin,
};
```

But I need firebase to use the appropriate service account for each project. My app is setup to use the production project when deployed in production, but the way I've set up admin.js (above) it always takes the development service-account credentials.

How can I set the service account credentials as an environment variable? Is there a way to add the key to firebase config in the console? Or should I just hard code in the production service account and live with that?

I found this in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env), but it doesn't appear to solve my problem.

```
serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccount.json');

const adminConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);
adminConfig.credential = admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount);
admin.initializeApp(adminConfig);
```

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by "*I need firebase to use the appropriate service account for each project*".  Service accounts are meant for you to use within your own backend code to access some Firebase and Google Cloud products.  You don't configure them in the console, you just generate them in the console and use them in your code.  I suggest editing your question to be more clear what specifically you're trying to achieve or what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: Thanks, DOug. Edited.  This bit: const serviceAccount = require("./service-account.json"); is  my dev service account. I need to pull in the prod service account when calling the function from production.  Is there a way to make this an environment variable? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: i wouldn't suggest you to follow my technique. But you can try something like this i have tried [in this project](https://github.com/AshishisLiquid/Firebase-Multiple-Project-in-Single-CodeBase)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify the configuration to use in an environment variable as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env) and then pick that up in your code.

**But** that should not be necessary in most cases, since **calling `admin.initializeApp()` without parameters already initializes the Admin SDK with the administrative credentials for the current project**.

Comment: Thanks, Frank. Calling admin.initializeApp() without parameters did the trick.